# Maximum flow of a graph and minimum capacity of a s-t cut

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, network-flow

> Question: Find the maximum flow and minimum capacity of a s-t cut of the following graph. The capacity on every edge is 1 . The continuous edges have a flow of 0 and the dotted straight edges have a flow of 1.  [image]

Step 1. Flow=0
[image]

Step 2. Use the fact that dotted edges gave a flow of 1 and continuous edges have a flow of 2. Total Flow= 3 [image]

Step 3: Augmented path 1. Total flow= 4.

[image: h]
[image]

Step 4: Augmented path 2. Total flow = 5.
[image]
[image]

Step5. There are no other augmented paths left.
[image]

S-t cut of minimal capacity :

[image]

Comment: I am confused how it happened that a different account posted this question, deleted it, and now you are posting it an hour later.

Comment: yes I forgot my password

Comment: If you have an idea  I would like to hear it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your proposed solution at all.  According to your description, the flows along the dotted edges *already* stand at their capacity of $\ 1\ $, so how could the paths $\ \text{s}$$\rightarrow$$\text{1}$$\rightarrow$$\text{a}$$\rightarrow$$\text{v}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $,$\ \text{s}$$\rightarrow$$\text{2}$$\rightarrow$$\text{w}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $ or $\ \text{s}$$\rightarrow$$\text{5}$$\rightarrow$$\text{e}$$\rightarrow$$\text{y}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $ be flow augmenting?

Two flow augmenting paths would appear to me to be $\ \text{s}$$\rightarrow$$\text{b}$$\rightarrow$$\text{v}$$\rightarrow$$\text{a}$$\rightarrow$$\text{u}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $ and $\ \text{s}$$\rightarrow$$\text{4}$$\rightarrow$$\text{e}$$\rightarrow$$\text{5}$$\rightarrow$$\text{d}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $.  Sending a flow of $\ 1\ $ along each of those paths will produce the set of flows represented in the following diagram:

[image]
(with the same convention that the flow along all continuous edges is $\ 0\ $, and the flow along all dotted edges is $\ 1\ $).

The total flow from $\ s\ $ to $ t\ $ with this assignment is $\ 5\ $, and the total flow through the cut comprising the edges $\ \text{u}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $,$\ \text{v}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $,$\ \text{w}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $,$\ \text{d}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $ and $\ \text{y}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $ is also $\ 5\ $. Therefore the maximum flow through the graph from from $\ s\ $ to $ t\ $ is $\ 5\ $ and the edges $\ \text{u}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $,$\ \text{v}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $,$\ \text{w}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $,$\ \text{d}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $,$\ \text{y}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $ constitute a cut of minimum capacity.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are right, but I have one question, normally with the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm they start with a flow of 0. So does this mean every edge (dotted and continuous) has   0/1  ?

Comment: What happens with the flow of the path v→ a  in the first path s→b→v→a→u→ t ? does the flow become 0 again because we go in opposite direction?

Comment: Yes, if the label $\  f/c $ on an edge means that the capacity of the edge is $\ c\ $, and the flow along it is $\ f\ $, and if the flow along all edges is zero, then every edge would be labelled $\ 0/1\ $. Given the convention that dotted edges represent those carrying a flow of $\ 1\ $ and continuous edges represent those carrying a flow of $\ 0\ $, however, I imagine every edge of the graph would be drawn continuous when all of them carry a flow of $0$. And yes, when you send a flow of $1$ backwards along the edge $\ v$$\rightarrow$$\ a\  $ the flow on that edge drops from $1$ to $0$.

Comment: does the cut also include the vertices t,u,v,w,x,y or only t? and I think x→ t should be d → t , is that right?

Comment: And  I edited my post..if at least I understood you right..?

Comment: Yes, $\ \text{x}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $ should have been $\ \text{d}$$\rightarrow$$\text{t}\ $, which it now is, after I corrected it.  Thank you for picking up the error.  Your updated solution now looks good.

Comment: In the terminology used by Ford and Fulkerson, a "cut" is just a set of all edges with initial node in a set $\ X\ $ and terminal node in a set $\ \overline{X}\ $, where $\ \{X,\overline{X}\}\ $ is a partition of the nodes of the graph with $\ s\in X\ $ and $\ t\in\overline{X}\ $.  The simplest way of specifying such a cut is just to list all the edges which constitute it, as I did in my answer, but you could also specify it by giving a pair of sets, one containing all the initial nodes of the edges in the cut, and the other containing all their terminal nodes.

Comment: For the cut in my answer, all the edges in it have the same terminal node, $\ t\ $, and the set of initial nodes of its edges is $\ \{u,v,w,d,y\}\ $, so you could give the pair of sets $\ (\{u,v,w,d,y\},\{t\})\  $ as a specification of the cut.

Comment: Thank you for your time!